# How to use loop function in r to add new data columns?

Tags: r, loops, extract, raster

I have 40 raster files about the data of different years. I would like to input them and add new columns in my original file called predictwgs. I use extract function to match my original data, but after running this code, it only adds one column called "i" instead of 40 new columns. How can I change this condition?

```
> dir<-"Desktop/Surface downwelling shortwave radiation"
> files<-list.files(path=dir, pattern=NULL, full.names = TRUE) for (i in
> 1:length(files)){   b <- raster(files[i])  
> predictwgs$i<-extract(b,as(predictwgs,'Spatial'))   }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case it is clear that in each step of the loop you assign values to the same variable called `predictwgs$i`. Here is your code in more legible form:

```
files<-list.files(path=dir, full.names = TRUE) 
sp <- as(predictwgs, "Spatial")

for (i in 1:length(files)){
    b <- raster(files[i])  
    predictwgs$i <- extract(b, sp)
}
```

`predictwgs$i` is not different than, for example `predictwgs$value

To use the value of looping variable `i` you could do something like this:

```
for (i in 1:length(files)){
    b <- raster(files[i])  
    predictwgs[[as.character(i)]] <- extract(b, sp)
}
```

Although it would appear that you avoid the loop and do:

```
b <- stack(files)
e <- extract(b, sp)
p <- cbind(predictwgs, e)
```

Here is an illustration of the difference between the two for loops.

Your approach:

```
d <- data.frame(x=c("a"))
for (i in 1:5){
    d$i <- i
}
d
#  x i
#1 a 5
```

What you intended:

```
d <- data.frame(x=c("a"))
for (i in 1:5){
   d[[paste0("v", i)]] <- i
}
d
#  x v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
#1 a  1  2  3  4  5
```